Spring Boot: loadUserByUsername Method Conflict - Need Help Resolving Issue
I am implementing the UserDetailsService interface in my Spring Boot application to use a custom loadUserByUsername method for authentication. However, I am encountering issues with my current implementation, as the method does not seem to work as expected.
I am using two separate services: CustomUserDetailsService and UserService. My requirement is to have two POST endpoints: /login-admin and /login-user. When I make a POST request to /login-admin, I want the authentication to use the CustomUserDetailsService. Similarly, when I make a POST request to /login-user, I want the authentication to use the UserService.
Currently, my implementation does not correctly differentiate between these two services because the loadUserByUsername method is conflicting.
here is the controller;
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private CustomUserDetailsService adminService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/login-admin")
    public String loginAdmin(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                             @RequestParam("password") String password,
                             Model model) {
        Admin admin = (Admin) adminService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (admin == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(password, admin.getPassword())) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "username or password is wrong.");
            return "login-admin"; // Incorrect login
        }

        // Successful login
        return "redirect:/admin-dashboard"; 
    }

    @PostMapping("/login-user")
    public String loginUser(@RequestParam("email") String email,
                            @RequestParam("password") String password,
                            Model model) {
        User user = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(email);

        if (user == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "email or passwrod is wrong.");
            return "login-user";
        }

        // Successful login
        return "redirect:/user-dashboard"; // Redirect to user dashboard
    }

}


here is the CustomUserDetailsService;
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Admin admin = adminRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (admin == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        } else {
            System.out.println(admin.getUsername());
        }

        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                .username(admin.getUsername())
                .password(admin.getPassword()) 
                .roles(admin.getRole())
                .build();

}


here is the UserService;
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + email);
        }

        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                .username(user.getEmail()) 
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .roles(user.getRole())
                .build();
    }
}


I tried using the @Qualifier method, but it didn't work. I want to properly connect "CustomUserDetailsService" with "/login-admin" and "UserService" with "/login-user" without any conflicts in the loadUserByUsername method.

What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Aren't the beans properly injected? How did you come to the conclusion that there's a conflict in the naming of the methods?

The issue is with two loadUserByUsername methods conflicting. The UserService's loadUserByUsername is pointing to:
Admin admin = (Admin) adminService.loadUserByUsername(username) and
User user = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(email)
However, I only want to point to:
User user = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(email)
Do you get it?

loadUserByUsername method returns UserDetails type. you cannot cast it to your own Admin or User class.
Your implementation is returning org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User which is an implementation of UserDetails. You might be getting confused with the above spring's User class and your own User and Admin classes.

It’s not about org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User. I tried using org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.Admin, but it didn’t work. The issue is with two loadUserByUsername methods conflicting. The UserService's loadUserByUsername is pointing to:
Admin admin = (Admin) adminService.loadUserByUsername(username) and
User user = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(email)
However, I only want to point to:
User user = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(email)
Do you get it?

I don't fully get it, but can you try UserDetails adminDetails = adminService.loadUserByUsername(username) and UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(email).
